# How to minimize sql select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an array of words like this one:

```
$word1 = array('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5',...,'test20');
```

I need to search in my table every row that has at least one of these words in the `text` column. So far, I have this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE text LIKE '$word1[0]' OR text LIKE '$word1[1]' 
OR ... OR text LIKE '$word1[20]'
```

But I see that this design isn't very efficient. Is there any way I can shorten this query, in such a way that I don't need to write out every word in the where clause?

Example `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE text IN ($word1)`

P.S.: this is an example of what I'm looking for, not an actual query I can run.

Comment: Actually, what you want is what you have already written. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TEXT IN ($word1).

Comment: It seems that learner wants to use LIKE and not an equal comparator, IN only search exact equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a table variable instead of a list to store your words then you can use something like:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
INSERT @T (Word)
VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3'), ('test4'), ('test5'), ('test20');

SELECT  * 
FROM    TABLE t
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    @T
            WHERE   t.Text LIKE '%' + word + '%'
        );
```

You can also create a table type to store this, then you can pass this as a parameter to a stored procedure if required:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList (Value VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedures @Words dbo.StringList READONLY
AS
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    TABLE t
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    @Words w
                WHERE   t.Text LIKE '%' + w.word + '%'
            );
GO
DECLARE @T dbo.StringList;
INSERT @T (Value)
VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3'), ('test4'), ('test5'), ('test20');

EXECUTE dbo.YourProcedure @T;
```

For more on this see [table-valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

---

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood your requirements as you used `LIKE` but with no wild card operator, in which case you can just use `IN`, however I would still recommend using a table to store your values:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
INSERT @T (Word)
VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3'), ('test4'), ('test5'), ('test20');

SELECT  * 
FROM    TABLE t
WHERE   t.Text IN (SELECT Word FROM @T);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SELECT like this without declaring an array:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE text IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5')
```

Comment: It seems that learner wants to use LIKE and not an equal comparator, IN only search exact equal.

Comment: In his SELECT he didn't use any wildcards so I thought using IN could be ok.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be :

1. Create a table in the database with the searched words in a column called word (by example)- by using wildcard if you need
2. use this kind of request

   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE, FILTER_TABLE
   WHERE TABLE.text LIKE FILTER_TABLE.word

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have access to SQL Server 2008 at the moment and SQLfiddle seems sick, it would seem you can use a [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to simplify the expression somewhat;

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
JOIN (SELECT w FROM (VALUES('word1'), ('word2'), ('word3'), ('word4')) AS a(w)) a
  ON test.text LIKE '%'+a.w+'%';
```

...which will search the text column in the test table for the words listed as values. If you don't want duplicates of rows where multiple words match, you can just add a `DISTINCT` to the select.

Note though that you may want to look into [fulltext indexing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) if you're doing extensive searches, a `LIKE` query to find words in a string in this way will *not* use any indexes, and will most likely be quite slow unless the data is already in memory.

Comment: Using `LIKE` in this way *can* use indexes, however as you say it is still expensive and using the index is not necessarily advantageous. This is why I would (and have) opted for `EXISTS` over `JOIN`, it is optimised as an anti-semi join (i.e. stops searching after a single match is found), and since a join on LIKE is likely to use a nested loop join it results in much lower IO (as fewer loops).